# Add white space in HTML page

Tags: html, css

I would like to add white space in HTML page. For now I use just basic

```
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
....
```

Is there other way to add white space in order to add some padding between the components?

Comment: Like... `padding: 4em`??

Comment: You can add margin-bottom to your object.

Comment: Firstly, it's worth asking are you familiar with CSS and how it works? Your question involves pure HTML markup, where as your answer will involve heavy use of CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

div,p,span and every html element add padding and margin.

like

```
p {margin-bottom:15px;} 
div {padding-bottom:15px;} 
span {padding:15px 15px 15px 15px;} 
p {margin:15px 15px 15px 15px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a space between elements, on the outside of the element, use [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).

To create a space on the inside of the element, use [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).

Also, see the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a `<div>` with a `min-height` / `height` of the amount of white space you want to have. Also add `width:100%` just to make sure.